# How are go channels and goroutines translated to webassembly?

Tags: go, webassembly, emscripten

Have been programming in Go from quite some time, and started looking into WebAssembly lately. While most of the things are straightforward, have a question around translating some of the Go specific constructs like channels and goroutines to wasm. Do they behave in the same way when used from JS as they would in Go (e.g. goroutines are exposed as async functions to JS, etc.)?

Comment: It's an interesting question. Have you tried it out yourself?

Comment: I have, they work normally in JS. I get that functions that block are not allowed in wasm and we should use goroutines to mitigate, but how does it translate internally to wasm?

Answer (score 10):

The WASM target of the go compiler does not currently support threads, or as Go calls them "procs".

This means that, from the perspective of a user of the language and simplifying a bit, a Go program running on WASM behaves as a Go program running with `GOMAXPROCS=1` on any other platform.

Crucially, as long as you use proper synchronization in your code, nothing should change from a correctness standpoint. This includes the semantics of channels and goroutines, in the same way these semantics do not change when you run your code with `GOMAXPROCS=1`.

The way this works is by including the go runtime (and its scheduler) in the built WASM module. The go runtime, exactly like in the case of `GOMAXPROCS=1` is able to multiplex execution of multiple goroutines even if only a single thread/proc is available. Note that as goroutines are green threads, the go runtime is able to suspend them when they block (e.g. waiting for I/O or to acquire a lock) and execute other goroutines that are not blocked. Once a goroutine becomes unblocked (e.g. because the I/O operation has completed, or the lock became available) it is queued again for execution and resumes from where it left off.

Comment: I don't fully understand "'multiplex execution of multiple goroutines", do you have recommended read/sources? From the JavaScript developer standpoint, to handle non-blocking calls, we are namely used to Promises or "setTimeout(cb, 0)" to push the call at the end of the stack. Calling "go func() {...}" is expected to achieve a similar result to using a promise?
Asking more details because what's seems (relatively) easy to understand for Go developers that build to WASM is not for JavaScript developers coming from the other side.

Comment: `go ...` spins up a goroutine that is essentially a green thread. The go runtime automatically and dynamically maps goroutines to threads (called procs or P) so that you can have a very high (~millions) number of goroutines regardless of the number of threads (including in case you have a single one). If a goroutine blocks (e.g. waiting for I/O or a lock) it is automatically suspended by the runtime and the next ready goroutine starts executing. When the blocked goroutine becomes ready to run (e.g.because the I/O op completed or the lock got released) it is queued for execution and resumes.

Comment: The tldr is that in go you don't need promises, async/defer or similar constructs, because the runtime transparently turns blocking operations into asynchronous ones, so you can write simpler, undecorated straight-line code and still get efficient asynchronous execution.